# Application ID for PayPal integration with Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working with Wordpress and Woocommerce in a local environment. It is required the app id in order to make the API calls. In Sandbox mode I am using APP-80W284485P519543T, this is mentioned here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/adaptive-payments/. To go Live I have created an app on Paypal and I tried to reach https://docs/api/goingLive/ (as it was written in the guide). I can't reach this page and I am not able to find the application id. How can I solve this issue?
Thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 2):

Adaptive Payments was deprecated in December of 2017. No APP IDs are available.

Switch to a plugin that uses a supported integration method, such as PayPal Checkout / Smart Payment Buttons.